# array pointer's vector c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am new to c++, i am on a check scanner's project and i am using an API that was provided with the scanner. Here's my code:

.h file :

```
#include <iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;
class Excella
{
public:
    vector<char*> getDevicesName();
};
```

.cpp file :

```
    vector<char*> Excella::getDevicesName()
    {
        DWORD dwResult;
        vector<char*> listeDevices;
        char pcDevName[128]="";
        int i = 6;

// the device's name is stored in the variable 'pcDevName'
        while ((dwResult = MTMICRGetDevice(i, (char*)pcDevName)) != MICR_ST_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND) {
            dwResult = MTMICRGetDevice(i, (char*)pcDevName);
            i++;
            listeDevices.push_back((char*) pcDevName);
        }
        return listeDevices;
    }
```

main.cpp

```
vector<char*> liste = excella.getDevicesName();
        if (liste.empty()!= true)
        {
            for (vector<char*>::iterator IterateurListe = liste.begin(); IterateurListe != liste.end(); ++IterateurListe)
            {   string str(*IterateurListe);
                auto managed = gcnew String(str.c_str());
                devices->Items->Add(managed);
            }
        }
        else {
            MessageBox::Show("The vector is empty");
        }
```

The problem is that i can get the right device number.. i just have some weird caracters.

Thank u for ur help.

Comment: Can you give a little more detail? What kind of weird characters are you getting?

Comment: For one `pcDevName` is already a `char*` so get rid of the unneeded `char*` cast.

Comment: For two, you never check the result of `dwResult` to make sure ` `MTMICRGetDevice` was successful before pushing the `pcDevName` into the vector; if it failed, that would explain why you see uninitialized garbage.

Comment: For three, `pcDevName` should be reinitialized each loop instead of being reused.

Comment: Use a debugger; it saves lives.

Comment: Yeah you're right i'll take this into consideration! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not surprising.

`char pcDevName[128]="";` will go out of scope at the end of of the function `vector<char*> Excella::getDevicesName()`. So any pointers to this that you've pushed to the vector will no longer be valid. Formally speaking, the behaviour of your program is *undefined*.

It's far simpler to use `std::vector<std::string>` instead. Remarkably, that's the only change you'd have to make: `push_back((char*) pcDevName)` will take a value copy of `pcDevName` (that's how the `std::string` constructor works).  Drop the unnecessary `(char*)` casts though.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
listeDevices.push_back((char*) pcDevName);
```

you are pushing into listeDevices a pointer to stack array. There are two problems with this - mayor one is that once your getDevicesName function ends, those pointers are invalid and use of them is Undefined, the other is that in each iteration of your loop you overwrite pcDevName and also your stored pointer content.

What you should do is to make listeDevices store std::string, ie. `std::vector<std::string>`, and then you can use `listeDevices.push_back((char*) pcDevName);` to safely store your names in a vector.